# Adding rating and commenting to individual fields

Tags: rating

I have a node with a CCK field file upload, which is using the image widget.
This node can have multiple images uploaded to it.

How can I add fivestar rating (or something similar), and comment to these individual pictures? How could I do it with other fields in general?

Answer (score 5):

The best way to solve this would be to use the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. All you would need to do is create a field collection with a rating and an image in it, and every time a new image is added, there would be a new rating next to it. The latest D7 version has come a long way and should work for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the proper way.  I would add a rating field also along with the field you are talking about. So enable it to be rated only when viewing the node.